# How to add prebuilt .so files in android studio1.3

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have 2 `.so` files `libA.so` & `libB.so` and few header files which I am trying to add to my project and currently I am getting an error "`undefined reference to <function name>`" linker failed to link module. please let me know the correct process to link them as gradle has changed to 2.5 for android studio 1.3

Comment: what you get exact error tell me.is it linkify error for path and where you are put the .so files

Comment: Error:(188) undefined reference to '<function-name>'
Error:error: ld returned 1 exit status
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:linkArmeabi-v7aDebugArmNativemoduleSharedLibrary'.
> A build operation failed.
      Linker failed while linking libA.so.
  See the complete log at: file: I have currently placed my .so files in app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a folder.

Comment: please create  3 folders  armeabi, armeabi-v7a, x86 and copy the same file into this folders

Comment: please let me know where do I need to create these 3 folders exactly?

Comment: projectname/app/src/main/jnilibs/ then create three folders and add this files